# Spotipy status code after a request python

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am using Spotipy to retrieve tracks by searching for song titles. I can't figure out how to get the status_codes for the query so that I can make my application more fail safe. Any ideas?

Here is a code snippet:

```
    sp = spotipy.Spotify()

    results = sp.search(q=title, type='track')

    #Want to check if status code of the sp.search command is 200 or something else. 
    #How?

    trackListing = results['tracks']['items']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like the internal spotipy api returns the status code.  It does however, throw a [SpotifyException](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/spotipy/client.py#L94) for HTTP errors.  Put your code in a try/except block and catch the `SpotifyException` to achieve the same result.